# How do you write super() in the UML format?Is it correct to write super(parameter: type): return type in the UML methods section?

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance, uml, constructors

Suppose you write a subclass that extends to a certain class and in that subclass, you use the super() method for your constructor.

Would you write "super(parameter: type): return type" in the UML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the large majority of cases, the `super()` call would *not* be reflected in your UML.

- `super` is not the name of an actual method (it is a language construct to call the super-class constructor), so you should not add it in the class diagram.
- In sequence diagrams, you *might* show the `super()` call if you want to show the parameters being passed on the the super class. In most cases, that information isn't all that useful or relevant for what you want to show in the diagram, so it is left out. If you *do* draw the `super()` call, it would be a self-call.
- The only other place where you might see the `super()` call is in the documentation of the constructor itself, if you use the UML diagrams to generate code from.